# How can I hide element within loop with react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, dictionary, npm

if i have this short react code and I am running into some trouble. I am trying to hide the header that button pertains to when I click the button next to it so that specfic header and button would disapear within the loop. How would I accomplish that?

ex: if i click the 1st button header one should disapear ("hey") and if I click the 3rd button, the 3rd header would disapear ("later)

```
import React from 'react';

class AppEX extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          ishidden: false,
            list: [
                { text: 'hey'},
                { text: 'bye'},
                { text: 'later'}
            ]
        };
    }

    hideHeader = e => {
      this.setState ={
        ishidden: true }

      
        
    };

    render() {
       
        return (
          <div>
          
             { this.state.list.map((s,idx)=> (
               
               <div key={idx}>
                 <h1>{s.text}</h1>
                 <button
                  onClick={(e) => this.hideHeader(e)}>
                    DONE
                  </button>

                 </div>
                 

             ))}

             </div>





          
        )}
}

export default AppEX;
```

Comment: Hint: Add an isHidden property to each item in list and pass index into function

Comment: as in add in to the json?

Comment: What json? None shown here. If you mean the state list array that is not json. By toggling a boolean in each item you can then use that to render or not render the heading

Comment: where would I add the boolean in each item?

Comment: `{ text: 'bye', ishidden:false}` then in render `{!s.ishidden && <h1>{s.text}</h1>}` then start figuring out how to access that element in the array when you click button so you can modify that object to set back into state

Comment: You shouldn't use index as a key. If each of your text strings are unique, you could use them as your key. Then you can remove the text strings or hide them using the flag mentioned by @charlietfl

Comment: @charlietfl so I should add ishidden to each list in the state first? then in the onclick in the function it chould change the value to true?

Comment: @SILENT they are all unique so you like s.text as the key?

Comment: That is the basic idea yes. Using the index as key is least of your issues right now and isn't critical to what you currently want to do

Comment: @charlietfl I am trying to access the element now. in the array. would I use the index to do that somehow?

Comment: If you know the index in the function....it's easy to find the object in the array. You could pass it in to hideHeader instead of e since you aren't doing anything with e

Comment: ok I am passing the index into hideheader now. but how do i access ishidden in the array since it is nested... i am passing the index successfully

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong with your code. Your code should approximately look as follows:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([
    { text: "hey" },
    { text: "bye" },
    { text: "later" }
  ]);
  const onClickBtn = (t) => () =>
    setList((l) =>
      l.map(({ text, hide }) => ({ text, hide: text === t ? true : hide }))
    );
  const display = list.map(
    ({ text, hide }) =>
      !hide && (
        <div key={text}>
          <h1>{text}</h1>
          <button onClick={onClickBtn(text)}>Hide</button>
        </div>
      )
  );
  return <div className="App">{display}</div>;
}
```

---

Even easier if your array was a list of strings

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState(["hey", "bye", "later"]);
  const onClickBtn = (t) => () => setList((l) => l.filter((s) => s !== t));
  const display = list.map((text) => (
    <div key={text}>
      <h1>{text}</h1>
      <button onClick={onClickBtn(text)}>Hide</button>
    </div>
  ));
  return <div className="App">{display}</div>;
};
```